# cv2.error in cv::copyMakeBorder,when I run python train.py --data data/hat.data --cfg cfg/yolov3-tiny.cfg to use yolo v3

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

When I use yolo v3 on pytorch to train some data, it throw a error like:

```
  Epoch   gpu_mem      GIoU       obj       cls     total   targets  img_size
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 433, in <module>
    train()  # train normally
  File "train.py", line 310, in train
    results, maps = test.test(cfg,
  File "D:\code\pytorch\yolo\yolov3\test.py", line 74, in test
    for batch_i, (imgs, targets, paths, shapes) in enumerate(tqdm(dataloader, desc=s)):
  File "D:\code\anaconda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\tqdm\std.py", line 1108, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "D:\code\anaconda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 345, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "D:\code\anaconda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 856, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "D:\code\anaconda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 881, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "D:\code\anaconda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\torch\_utils.py", line 394, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
cv2.error: Caught error in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\code\anaconda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\worker.py", line 178, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "D:\code\anaconda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "D:\code\anaconda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "D:\code\pytorch\yolo\yolov3\utils\datasets.py", line 432, in __getitem__
    img, ratio, pad = letterbox(img, shape, auto=False, scaleup=self.augment)
  File "D:\code\pytorch\yolo\yolov3\utils\datasets.py", line 630, in letterbox
    img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=color)  # add border
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\copy.cpp:1421: error: (-215:Assertion failed) top >= 0 && bottom >= 0 && left >= 0 && right >= 0 && _src.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::copyMakeBorder'


               Class    Images   Targets         P         R   mAP@0.5        F1:   0%|          | 0/5 [00:08<?, ?it/s](test)
```

I try to find some solution on Google.https://github.com/facebook/Surround360/issues/201 ,but it doesn't help me. So please help me solve this problem.

Here is some of my train images.
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to see the context of the error (i.e. your code). You are passing in a malformed image or specifying invalid border dimensions.

Comment: The title to this question is really unfortunate. I would change it by I'm not sure what to change it to. an chen, can you take a moment to try and give this a more meaningful title? You'll have a much better chance of getting a satisfactory answer that way.